# External HDD spinning even when laptop lid is closed

Tags: kali-linux, hard-disk, battery

I am having a 160GB SATA HDD in which I have installed Kali-Linux, last night I just closed the lid of the laptop considering that will continue my work tomorrow from here but in the morning I noticed that the HDD was vibrating (spinning) and laptop's battery has fallen throughout the night. This doesn't really happen with the builtin SATA HDD of my laptop. Can anyone tell me the configuration to disable HDD working when I close the lid?

Comment: Is the external HDD connected via USB? If so, have you tried using a different USB port? There might also be issues related to some of the similar questions already answered on here.  e.g. "hdparm -B 127", "smartd was continually running", "disk firmware", etc.

Comment: Yes, its connected via usb port. Will try on some other port. Didnt get your hdparm stuff

Comment: Sometimes laptops have ports which are designed to always give power so that you can charge your mobile by connecting. These are often marked by a lightening bolt symbol. This can often be disabled in the laptop's BIOS, saving power.